# I am having Huawei Site Kit Error Code:10017

Tags: java, android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Hi there I am getting this error while getting nearby locations.

P.S My device has no sim card let me know if you think this will be a problem.

```
responseErrorCode errorCode = 10017 errorReason = SIGNATURE_INVALID
```

I have searched here but couldn't find the reason.
[Result Code link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/result-code-0000001051056179-V1)

Here is the certificate mentioned in build.gradle

```
  signingConfigs {
    config {
        storeFile file('keystore.jks')
        storePassword '*****'
        keyPassword '*****'
        keyAlias 'key'
        v1SigningEnabled true
        v2SigningEnabled true
    }
}
```

Here is the SS of huawei console.
[image: Huawei console]

Here the complete log.

> I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResult:0
> I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: baseCallBack.onComplete
> I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code0, api_name:location.requestLocationUpdates, app_id:104565291|, pkg_name:com.ogoul.kalamtime, session_id:*, transaction_id:104565291pdates20210813103016514894175, resolution:null
> I/HMSSDK_RequestLocationUpdatesTaskApiCall: |71d9bb75-f532-45e2-8e2f-4cbd89a41eb2|doExecute
> I/HMSSDK_TidCacheManager: |71d9bb75-f532-45e2-8e2f-4cbd89a41eb2|list to find size is:1
> I/HMSSDK_TidCacheManager: |71d9bb75-f532-45e2-8e2f-4cbd89a41eb2|find tid in list, tid:71d9bb75-f532-45e2-8e2f-4cbd89a41eb2
> I/HMSSDK_RequestLocationUpdatesTaskApiCall: |71d9bb75-f532-45e2-8e2f-4cbd89a41eb2|doExecute onLocationResult
> I/HMSSDK_RequestLocationUpdatesTaskApiCall: |71d9bb75-f532-45e2-8e2f-4cbd89a41eb2|modify numUpdates with callback, numUpdates:2147483647 , locationSize:1
> I/HMSSDK_RequestLocationUpdatesTaskApiCall: |71d9bb75-f532-45e2-8e2f-4cbd89a41eb2|handleOnResultMessage code:1
> I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResult:0
> I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: baseCallBack.onComplete
> I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:1, error_code10017, api_name:site.nearbySearch, app_id:104565291|, pkg_name:com.ogoul.kalamtime, session_id:*, transaction_id:104565291Search20210813103016121420275, resolution:null
> E/HmsSiteKit_NearbySearchTaskApiCall_73: responseErrorCode errorCode = 10017 errorReason = SIGNATURE_INVALID
> I/TAG: Error : 010017  SIGNATURE_INVALID
> I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApiManager: sendRequest
> I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: post msg api_name:site.nearbySearch, app_id:104565291|, pkg_name:com.ogoul.kalamtime, sdk_version:50200300, session_id:*, transaction_id:104565291Search20210813103022971741021, kitSdkVersion:0, apiLevel:10
> I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: in baseRequest + uri is :site.nearbySearch, transactionId is : 104565291Search20210813103022971741021
> I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: init uri:site.nearbySearch
> I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResultCallback

Comment: Have you generated a signing certificate fingerprint and added it on the Appgallery Connect website (see [this guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html#3))? If so, make you that you signed your app with the signing certificate that matches that fingerprint.

Comment: @Michael I have already allowed site api in manage apis and app signing certificate is also added.

Comment: @Michael I have edited the question with SS

Comment: getting nearby locations failed or success? Is there more error log  about this question?

Comment: @Anna obviously it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue.
Issue was my testing device doesn't have a Sim card it and automatically devices get time according to service providers.
Simply insert sim card and install few updates and BINGO. error solved.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> responseErrorCode errorCode = 10017 errorReason = SIGNATURE_INVALID
> ```

This error code indicates that the request signature is invalid.

It is recommended that you to check whether the device time was manually changed. If so, change it back and try again.

For details, See [Result Codes](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/webapi-error-code-0000001050163432).

Comment: Time is already set automatically using Network Time zone.
Anyhow I have changed it to manual and vice versa but still no success.

Comment: hi@Uzair Mughal, You can use Postman to test the WebAPI and check whether any error is reported. like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGl8B.png .See [Docs link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/webapi-nearby-search-0000001050163873).

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
I have checked the key with post man request it is working fine there.

Comment: hi@Uzair Mughal, could you pls provide your complete log, so that we can analyse your problem.

Comment: I have edited the question with the log. Kindly have a look.

Comment: hi@Uzair Mughal, sorry but according the log you provided above , it's still hard to  locate this issue. Could you kindly help us with some more log information to locate this issue? The procedure for capturing logs is as follows:
1. Run the following command to connect to the device: adb logcat –v time > D:\hwsite.txt
2. Reproduce the fault.
3. Press Ctrl+C to complete log capture.

Comment: Also, The log format provided is a bit unclear. Could you mind adjust the format before providing it? Thx a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your time but the issue is solved.
Kindly check my answer.

Comment: Great! Should you need help with anything else, please feel free to reach out back to us.